# Is Super Mario Bros. in Nintendo World Championship 1990 the complete game?

Tags: super-mario-bros

In the Nintendo World Championship 1990 game, is it possible to completely play through Super Mario Bros?

By this, I mean not collecting 50 coins, but continue playing normally taking warp zones and going through the levels as fast as you can.

Could you eventually reach Bowser in level 8-4 and rescue the princess? Or are there unavoidable coins in the middle which would guarantee that you would get 50 coins before that happened?

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't say that it is the full game. Cartridge storage space was scarce back then. Then again, I haven't own a copy so don't take this as an answer.

Comment: "Nintendo world championship 1990" was only produced in very small volumes, so it's likely that development time would have been more important than cart cost. Cart storage space was scarce but not so scarce that a few early NES games (which were much smaller than later NES games) couldn't be crammed into one cart.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is yes, it is possible to finish a complete game
Here is the end screen:

[image]

After this the game repeats as in the original Mario Bros, that is, starting from World 1-1, with the goombas replaced by buzzy beatles

We are not allowed to change world with the B button
The score and coin counts reset to 0, but the timer of the game cart continues

[image]

Once the timer is up, only the current score in mario is counted as the NWC score

[image]